# Building a Sturdy Wall

Tags: fallout-4

When building a settlement you have to build defenses to make sure it does not get attacked. Looking at junk fencing I had the brilliant idea to wall the settlement in and create a gate to limit The Avenue of attack so it will be easier to defend.

The problem is the fencing does not attach to each other like it does in super mutant or raider camps. Since it does not attach there are many holes which you can slip through. Is there any way to attach fencing or at least make the fencing impenetrable?

Comment: fwiw the best sturdy wall imo is the foundation piece under wooden -> floors

Comment: I agree but the problem is finding concrete. Also it doesn't fit the aesthetics of fallout walls. :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fencing does connect to each other. You just need to use the right parts... using wire fence as an example, you'd need to use the fence posts in conjunction with the other components available in that section to build a fence.

Here is a wire fence I built earlier with each of the different components used marked on it:

[image: here is a fence...]

This also applies to picket fencing once you've unlocked the ability to build that, or if you're re-arranging existing picket fencing.

With the large junk fences, they don't connect to each other - you'll have to spend some time piecing it together bit by bit until you've achieved what you want. It is possible to build a junk fence that doesn't have sufficiently large gaps that enemies can just walk past it but you'll need to position each panel individually.

[image: junk fence]

Comment: So there is no way to attach large junk fencing like what appears in Raider and Super Mutant camps? Well that's a bummer

Comment: It's also not possible to stack junk fence on top of each other, as appears in some areas of the game.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

1. Enter console ( ~ Key)
2. Type: "TCL", then press ENTER
3. Console should read "Collision -> OFF", if it does, press ~ again, to exit Console

[[[note: this will allow your character to clip through anything in game, even the earth. Type TCL in console again to turn it off, try not to walk into the sun.]]]

4. Enter the Workshop Menu, and select a junk wall (Or anything, really)
5. Place a junk wall, now, place another junk wall as close as you want to the 1st junk wall.

[[[You'll notice that no matter how close you place the wall (or anything, really), it remains green! You can even place them directly insinde one another!]]]

***Misplace a wall? Trying to place a wall directly next to an already placed wall OUT of TCL?

[[[You'll also notice that you cannot select the wall again after it is placed while in TCL. To fix this, simply exit TCL, returning to normal collision, then enter TCL into console again. You will be able to select it now]]]

[[[You will also notice you cannot place a wall through a wall that has been previously placed while NOT in TCL. To solve this, select the wall (the one you placed normally) that can not be clipped through WHILE in TCL, then release it. This will place the wall (the one you placed normally, while not in TCL) on the hypothetical layer that exists while you place things in TCL. You will now be able to place a new wall, inside of the previously placed wall (the one you previously placed normally)... this is confusing I know, I hope it helps. It may take some playing around.]]]

Here's a link to a video of me awkwardly explaing how this works:

Comment: Can you do this for PS4?

Comment: @TylerWeaver There's no console commands on PS4/Xbox1. This only works on PC

Answer (score 2):

I use fence posts to fill in small gaps between the fence sections or the fence and the impenetrable object next to it.  You may have to use 3 or 4 to fill in the gap, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to make a wall and it will make it look a little better when using certain junk fences use them in conjunction with "structures>wood>walls>wall end". There are two on that is wood and corrugated metal and the top bar over hangs; the second  the top is not level. Use the first one and the link up as you can see[image]

It works well with most but I have not tested them all. Also, I'm not far in the game.

EDIT I have unlocked picket fences through a comic and maybe just maybe there's one out there that connects junk fences together. OH and if you go to stuctures to miscellaneous spiked poles fit nicely into gaps aswell

Answer (score 2):

You can put them on floor mats. Every object on the mat will clip through everything else, as long as you can place the mat. You can also remove the mat afterwards, but the fence might jump or sink a little bit from/in the Ground

Edit: Doorframes and turrets won't work. theyll just keep floating. looks funny though :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use wooden walls -- they snap together and use less resources (no rubber required, just wood and steel)